# Cannot delete .git directory

Tags: ssh, git, rm

I try to run `sudo rm -rf .git/` but the terminal return the following message:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘.git/objects/pack/pack-3818f69fa7bd64ef22c94c0bf630c18333cd5da9.idx’: Operation not permitted 
rm: cannot remove ‘.git/objects/pack/pack-3818f69fa7bd64ef22c94c0bf630c18333cd5da9.pack’: Operation not permitted
```

Also, I try to run `chattr -i filename`, but it return an error too:

```
chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on .git/objects/pack/pack-3818f69fa7bd64ef22c94c0bf630c18333cd5da9.idx
```

Comment: Do you write permission?  `chmod -R +w .git`and then `rm -rf .git` should work.

Comment: Do `ls -l` on both of the files.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with mount options or permissions of a parent directory. My `pathlld` script will show you what's up. See https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld.git - Bash script to answer "Why can't I read/write that file?"

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution: I just rename the .git folder to another name and remove it.